# iPhone Share Wifi with MacBook Via Bluetooth?

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, iphone, bluetooth

My MacBook is unable to connect to a wireless network due to airport card issue. While I figure out how to fix/replace the card, is there a way to share my iPhone's connection to a wireless network with my MacBook (e.g. via Bluetooth)?

Answer (score 2):

That all depends.  If by "wireless network" you are referring to an EDGE (2G) or 3G/4G connection then it would be as simple as going in to your iPhone's settings and turning tethering on.  However, in the much more likely scenario that you are referring to a Wi-Fi network then the answer is a simple "No" unless you are not afraid of jailbreaking your device.  In case you are unaware, jailbreaking an iPhone is a very simple and completely legal operation that removes many of Apple's restrictions and allows the iPhone to run third-party apps.  If you have jailbroken your iPhone then there are a number of apps that could do what you are looking for.  I recommend MyWi, though I believe that PDANet would work as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes you were correct in assuming the latter scenario, a wi-fi network. I've heard of jailbreaking, but haven't done it. I'm glad MyWi or PDANet will work for this.

Comment: If you are interested in jailbreaking your device, there is a good guide [here](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-5.1-ios-semi-untethered-on-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-using-redsn0w-0.9.10b6/) that should help

Answer (score 0):

Well what I understand from your Question is you want to share iPhone connection to your Macbook. You can do it. Follow this:

1)Just go to **Settings--> Personal Hotspot(Below WiFi)**

2) Turn on Personal Hotspot where you will have two option for sharing your internet: Via USB and Via WiFi.

Since your Wifi has problem select Via USB and plug in your iPhone to Macbook and start surfing.